# RF Switch vs Zero-Ohm Resistors

Tags: rf, pcb-design

Does anyone have any experience using zero-ohm resistors in an RF signal path to select antennas? I've typically used RF switches for this purpose, but that's also when it was necessary to allow the antenna selection to be changed "in the field". But for cases where the antenna selection is a manufacture-time option, I'm considering simple zero-ohm resistors (i.e. populating one or the other to complete the particular signal path to the antenna).

Of course using zero-ohm resistors for this sort of thing in a digital circuit path is a no-brainer, but I'm specifically interested if there is anything I should watch out for since this is an RF path (two separate paths: 868-915MHz and 2.4GHz). Can I treat the zero-ohm resistor as essentially being part of the PCB trace, or will this cause problems?

PS - The two antenna path options are an on-board ceramic antenna and an off-board connector. The zero-ohm resistor would be a surface-mount component.

Comment: A zero ohm resistor will have a (slightly) different self-inductance than a track; whether that makes a difference in your design I do not know.

Comment: A SMD 0 ohm resistor or capacitor should work fine.  Just keep the "tee" part short where the signal paths split.  900 Mhz and 2.4 GHz are still fairly low frequency, and you aren't building a spectrum analyzer that needs 0.1 dB flatness over 20 GHz.  If the tee junction is a problem you could use a wilkinson splitter and terminate the side you don't want.

Comment: @Evan--Interesting idea with the Wilkinson splitter, but as you say, I doubt it will be necessary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You rarely need DC continuity to an antenna, so I've always used a normal SMD 10pF to 100pF ceramic capacitor, depending on frequency. They're already used on the board, and tend to be cheaper than zero-ohm resistors, as we buy them by the bazillion rather than the handful.

Comment: That's a really good point! I'll go that route for now.

Comment: What formula do you use to select the capacitor value?

Comment: Other things being equal, and assuming that we're on a 50 ohm track, whatever value gives 'a few ohms'. Any more would start to influence the signal level. Any less is unnecessary and might start to cause other problems, like conducting low frequency noise, or generating a suck-out through an SRF that's too low with cheap capacitors. Hence my range of 10 to 100pF for your range of 900M to 2.4GHz. 10p/2.4G is about 6ohms, 100p/900M is less than 2. Maybe 6 ohms is a bit high, you shouldn't go any higher without careful thought, anything down to 0.1 ohms should be OK.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. What I'm trying to learn is how you derive those values. Is there a standard formula you're using to calculate the resistance (i.e. based on the track resistance, the center frequency, the cap value, etc.)?

Comment: magnitude of capacitor impedance (ohms) = 1/(2.pi.f.C) (Hz and pF). The value of 'a few ohms' is not derived, it's 'rule of thumb'. 50 ohm impedance (not resistance) track is the most common one to use routing about on the board as it's (a) a convenient value to implement physically (microstrip width = 2 x dielectric thickness on FR4 and RO4350), and (b) it interfaces with 50 ohm connectors and test equipment, which makes debugging possible. Ask if anything else is unclear.

Comment: @Neiil_UK Of course there's a lot to be said for the experience of doing this for while, but I do have a clearer understand of it now. Based on my understanding, I'm curious about the choice of 10p for the 2.4G cap. If 6 ohms in a bit high, using a 20p cap would cut this in half, right? And if so, wouldn't that be a better choice?

Comment: @eric the key word was 'maybe' a bit high. I was just whacking nominal figures down without doing detailed design, 10-100 has a better ring to it than 20-100! Anyhows, a 6johm impedance (j, reactive) in a 50ohm system would introduce <0.02dB loss, so, really, less than any other defect in the system, so negligible. It could be a 5pF cap, 12ohms, for 0.06dB, still nothing. The main thing is chill, it's not too important, a few ohms is OK.

Comment: @eric to put it another way ... If you were building filter, you'd want a specific value capacitor. In this position, you have several orders of magnitude to choose from. The penalty for getting too small a cap is a little extra loss. The potential penalties for too large a cap would be conduction of low frqeuency noise that would be otherwise filtered out, and a possible suck out if using a cheap ordinary cap - special high Q wideband coupling caps are available, but expensive.

Comment: Thanks for all the details. I like to understand what's behind a particular engineering choice, and I have a much better grasp of this now.

Answer (score 3):

Zero ohm resistors are commonly used in RF signal paths as a population option to select between an internal antenna and an external antenna. The key is to overlap one pad of the two resistors and make them at right angles to each other. For one example see Texas Instruments reference designs for their CC1310 Launchpad, CC1350 Launchpad, etc. Neil is correct too; sometimes we'll use 100pF caps instead. When in doubt check with the IC manufacturer; they know the RF part really well and can help.

Comment: Interesting (and makes sense). Do you happen to know if the 90-degree orientation is "required" or "better", vs say a 180-degree "T" orientation?

Answer (score -2):

Examine the geometry of  your antenna track to ground W/gap ratio for controlled impedance. Thus a 1x2 LxW ratio is about half the inductance of a 2x1 ratio part. e.g. 603. 60x30 mil

Inductance is all about LxW ratio per unit length.

So a 1206 part has the same inductance as a 0402 but more capacitance and gap above ground plane depends on copper+solder thickness.

Normally a Pin diode is used for antenna switches.