# 0R resistor performance in RF Pi Network

Tags: antenna

I have a prototype board for Sigfox and LoRaWAN (915MHz) with spaces to install components for a Pi network on the antenna.

We're using a 0R 0603 SMD resistor in place of the inductor, and no capacitors at the moment. I.e. we have bypassed the Pi network.

I was wondering, is a standard 0603 0R resistor ok for the link or do we need special RF rated resistors even though it's 0R?

Comment: related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304354/rf-switch-vs-zero-ohm-resistors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtually all thin film 0603 resistors will be fine. Here is a table of model parameters taken from real resistor measurements made by Vishay: -

[image]

As you can see, capacitance is tens of femto farads and inductance is easily sub 1 nH. Table taken from [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjH9Orq0KLZAhWBCMAKHZEMB4QQFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vishay.com%2Fdoc%3F60107&usg=AOvVaw3YTna33x8rTyb6xFhNXnu0).

Comment: Thanks that’s great info. FYI I was wondering if the resistor could be attenuating our signal. Turns out the u.fl socket was soldered backwards making the RF path open circuit!

Comment: Nice find!!!!!!

Comment: The study is specifically about thin film resistors. Would _thick film_ resistors give significantly different values?

Comment: Why don’t you formalise that into a site question @pfabri

Comment: @Andyaka Didn't think it was worth it. I thought asking this (imho) highly-related question here was a better strategy.